# Python - PyDash example of reduce with accumulator

Tags: python-3.x, reduce, accumulator, pydash

Looking for a code example using Python’s PyDash module of reduce with the accumulator arg, and how to output that with previous and current.

Answer (score 3):

`pydash.reduce_` is not very different from the built-in `functools.reduce`.

A good example for using the accumulator (or the `initial` parameter in functools' case) is to use it as a "neutral element":

```py
def factorial(n):
    return pydash.reduce_(range(1, n), lambda total, x: total*x, accumulator=1)
```

In this case, `1` is used as the initial value and doesn't affect the result (since 1*x=x), but more importantly: It will be used as the return value if there are no elements in `range(1, n)`.

And indeed, `factorial(0) == factorial(1) == 1` is the required result.